# Bootstrap Modal - Add server code ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, twitter-bootstrap-3

Net webform application implementing Bootstrap. Currently I have a label and a text box displayed in Bootstrap - Modal to which Im trying to send the data from the server c# file. For some reason the Modal disappears and doesnt show anything on the UI.

ASPx file

```
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" runat="server" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>
<%--<asp:Button ID="Button1" role="button" type="button" runat="server" Text="Modal" class="btn btn-lg btn-success"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/>--%>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

C# file

```
protected void Click_Me(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "test label";
    TextBox1.Text = "text box text";

    modal_Img.Src = "test path";
}
```

Please advice

ps : do i need to use an Update panel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Update Panel would likely not be the best solution for this because only a partial amount of the html is updated and the Javascript/Jquery for the modal is not being called again after the partial postback.

You need some way of invoking the Javascript again after the postback. You could invoke the Javascript needed to open the modal on your `Click_Me` event.

```
    protected void Click_Me(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // do stuff
      Label1.Text = "test label";
      TextBox1.Text = "text box text";
      modal_Img.Src = "test path";

      // make sure the modal opens
      ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "script", "<script type='text/javascript'>$( document ).ready(function() { $('#MyModal').modal('show')});</script>", false);
    }
```

Comment: My answer assumes that you are calling the `Click_Me` event from a button within the modal. Otherwise, the default functionality for the modal window is to close when you click outside of it. Either way, you'll want some way for it to open back up and display your update(s) after a postback.

Comment: Hi So i modified the code as below - added a button - <asp:Button ID="Button5" role="button" OnClick="Click_Me" runat="server" Text="Modal" class="btn btn-lg btn-success"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/>  and then added the below in c# ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "script", "<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function() { $('#MyModal').modal('show')});</script>", false); - but i dont see the modal appearing - ??? Am i missing something here

Comment: @Vivek akk Did that work for you? It's hard to say that `data-toggle` and `data-target` will work during an asp.net postback but adding the `ScriptManager` code will essentially inject the javascript needed to open or re-open the modal when your page is reloaded.

Comment: It didnt work dude - I removed the  <a> trigger and removed the comment on the button which i added the onclick event. then i added the invoke code as suggested by u in c#. Still doesnt seem to work. Do i need to do anything else ?

Comment: Dude i did add the update panel and script manger. It now works but the problem is the Modal appears twice one before and after server logic ran.

Comment: @Vivek akk try removing either the server logic (`ScriptManager`) or the call on the button it's self... (`data-toggle` and `data-target`). It seems it's now being called twice, both on the client side and on the server side.

Comment: I tested your code without the update panel and it worked. I formed the button tag as such...`<asp:Button ID="Button5" role="button" OnClick="Click_Me" runat="server" Text="Modal" class="btn btn-lg btn-success"/>` and the event coded in my answer

Comment: Thanks dude, it now renders only once, But one other issue. Once the page loads - on first click of the button it does nothing, but when i click again then it loads the modal, and works fine on subsequent clicks. Only on first load i have to click the button twice to make it work. any thoughts ? appreciate your time.

Comment: never mind dude it works when i remove data-toggle and data-target

Comment: @Vivek akk Awesome. Glad I could help. I just completed a project not long ago that used WebForms and implemented Bootstrap. I've ran into similar issues. With the script block above, you can inject Javascript from the server side when it gets ignored on the client side. Sometimes WebForms does not play nicely with heavy client-side scripting due to the postbacks.